# how to Add an int value into array list in drools

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor, drools-flow

I am new to drools.I am using 5.6.0 version of drools. I want to add an int value into an ArrayList when the variable satisfies some condition.

```
package com.sample  
import com.sample.PojoDRLListIteration;  
import java.util.ArrayList;  
import java.util.List;  
rule "Available firmwares for hardware 3"  
  salience 61  
when   
  PojoDRLListIteration: PojoDRLListIteration($listOfHardware: listOfHardware)  
  hardware_version:Integer() from $listOfHardware 
  PojoDRLListIteration1: PojoDRLListIteration($x: Hardwaretobechecked && $x == 3)     
  PojoDRLListIteration2: PojoDRLListIteration($listOfFirmware: listOfFirmware)
  firmware_version: Double() from $listOfFirmware
  PojoDRLListIteration($listOfAddons : listOfAddons) 
  Addon_version: Double() from $listOfAddons
  $l2: ArrayList()     
  $finalresult: PojoDRLListIteration(hardware_version >= 3 && 
                                     firmware_version > 1.2 &&
                                     Addon_version >= 1.1  )
then    
  $l2.add(hardware_version);
  System.out.println("value added"+$l2.get(0));
end
```

Control is not entering the then part. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll have to add the Java code for  PojoDRLListIteration and the code creating and inserting all of the facts. There are several issues with this rule but one has to see the Java code for proposing a fix.

Comment: I Have added global list and now I can add values into list